# Count the occurrence of ''reverse'' strings match in two columns

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I am now dealing with a table in R as follows:

```
A B 09-2016
B A 09-2016
A C 10-2016
C A 11-2016
A B 12-2016
```

I have tried to count the number of occurrences of same row values in the first two columns, e.g., "A B" occurs twice in the table, and I use the following R code:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(data)
dt[, list(Freq =.N, V3), by=list(V1,V2)]
```

And I can get the following output:

```
A B 2 09-2016
B A 1 09-2016
A C 1 10-2016
C A 1 11-2016
A B 2 12-2016
```

Now I want to count the occurrence of **reverse** pattern, e.g., "A B" and "B A", as the same value and get the following output:

```
A B 3 09-2016
B A 3 09-2016
A C 2 10-2016
C A 2 11-2016
A B 3 12-2016
```

My question is: how can I change the above code to deal with this case? Or is there another way? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an attempt by using `pmin` and `pmax` to paste the two columns sorted.

```
library(data.table)

dt[, freq := .N, by = .(new = paste(pmin(V1, V2), pmax(V1, V2)))][]

#   V1 V2 V3      V4 freq
#1:  A  B  2 09-2016    3
#2:  B  A  1 09-2016    3
#3:  A  C  1 10-2016    2
#4:  C  A  1 11-2016    2
#5:  A  B  2 12-2016    3
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(V1 = c("A", "B", "A", "C", "A"),
    V2 = c("B", "A", "C", "A", "B"),
    V3 = c("09-2016", "09-2016", "10-2016", "11-2016", "12-2016"))
dt[, tempvar := paste0(sort(c(V1,V2)), collapse = ""), by = 1:nrow(dt)]    
dt[, freq := .N, by = tempvar][, tempvar:=NULL]
```

Comment: I was referencing the same data table used by the OP. Have edited the answer to include that explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the `max` and `min` of the 2 columns V1,V2 initially and `group by` those values so that a symmetric pair frequency is summed up.

```
dt<-dt[,.(mx=max(as.character(V1),as.character(V2)),mn=min(as.character(V1),as.character(V2)))
       ,by=.(V1,V2,V3)]
dt<-dt[,.(Freq =.N,V1,V2,V3), by=.(mx,mn)][,.(V1,V2,V3,Freq)]
dt
```

[`R-Fiddle`](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=UHP88N87&version=1)